# Do the Hasideans have a connection to the House of David?

Tags: history, king-david, shevatim-12-tribes

What primary sources have scholars examined to investigate potential genealogical ties between the [Hasideans](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hasideans) and the house of David or other tribes? Does linguistic analysis of the name "Hasid" provide any clues? Have comparisons to other aristocratic groups at the time yielded relevant information?

Comment: All I could find with a pretty robust search is that King David was considered the "original chasid": https://www.sefaria.org/Abarbanel_on_II_Samuel.7.22.1?vhe=Abarbanel,_Tel_Aviv_1960&lang=bi, which does not answer your question. It seems like a historical scholarly search is needed. Hatzlacha. What makes you think they are related to David btw?

Comment: It's actually debated whether the Hasideans was the name of a particular group or should simply be translated as "pious ones", i.e. a random group of pious people.

Comment: Yeah. They considered themselves "extra pious", that's all.

Comment: The historians would tell you "once they won the right to worship as they pleased, they saw themselves as too pious to join their countrymen in continuing the fight for autonomy."